# Is this an acceptible way to check a session

Tags: php

Currently, I want to check many pages if a session is set or not and redirect if the session is not set, would this be an acceptable way to do it?

```
function checkLogin()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION["userId"]) ){
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
}


session_start(); 
checkLogin();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nothing is wrong with it.

You could also check if session is started

```
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE OR !isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header('index.php');
}
```

This [tutorial](https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was overthinking it a bit, I'll read the tutorial too